# BlackBerry - 9860 shows app in small window - not using whole screen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

One of our clients has come back to us today with a bug that has been found on the Torch 9860 (running OS 7.0).

It seems my app is running in a small box in the centre of the screen, with a big blue border surrounding it. If the soft keyboard is not showing, there is a black box where the keyboard would be.

This issue has not been reported before on other devices, and the app has been "in the wild" for a while. I have not seen it on our test devices - but do not have a Torch 9860 to test with.

I have attached photos of the app running on the device. The blue border is the problem - normally my app would fill the whole screen. I did not create the blue border (to the best of my knowledge).

Apologies for the photos - this is what they sent to us.

---

Showing the app running in a small box surrounded by the blue border. Note the black space where the keyboard would be if it was required.

[image: no keyboard]

---

Showing the app with the soft keyboard visible.

[image: soft keyboard]

---

With some googling, I found 1 possible reference to this issue to do with an instant messaging app not showing correctly on 9860. Feedback was that they were looking into it.

- I wonder who else has seen this, or can recommend solutions?

---

Updates

- runs fine on the 9860 emulator
- seems to be mentioned in this thread: [Blackberry OS 7 Compatibility failed with 9860/9850 device](http://forums.techarena.in/portable-devices/1434483.htm)

Comment: Perhaps it is related to compatibility mode. When application runs in this mode it may look very strange. I would recompile this app with SDK 7.0 and check again. Does the problem persist in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Rafael (left answer in a comment to my question).

Based on the comment I told the client to run the app in **compatibility mode** (accessed through the system options - application options menu). This seems to have fixed the problem without me having to recompile for SDK 7.0 (also I don't have to start supporting multiple OS's yet).

Answer (score -1):

I already had the blackscreen on bottom when the keyboard should be popped. But it happened rarely and get resolved with an update of the Blackberry

Ask for the OS version/platform of the Blackberry, and propose a update to him, if available.